# Better way to scan large table to delete records without interrupting ongoing inserts

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a table with ~50M rows in it (UrlLog). A handful of application instances insert 4000-5000 new rows in total into this table every minute. Each night a job runs that deletes every record in this row where the primary key is not referenced by any rows in two other tables (these two tables contain about 50M (OutLog) and 150M (InLog) rows).

I'm having some trouble with selects, deletes, and inserts interfering and causing timeouts on any operations accessing this table while the clean up process is running.

Here are the tables, essentially:

```
CREATE TABLE UrlLog (
  Id BIGINT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  Hash UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL,
  Protocol TINYINT NOT NULL,
  DomainId SMALLINT NOT NULL,
  Path NVARCHAR(4000) NOT NULL,
  Query NVARCHAR(4000) NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE INDEX IX_UrlLog_Hash NONCLUSTERED (Hash)
)

CREATE TABLE InLog (
  Id BIGINT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  UrlId BIGINT NOT NULL,
  Timestamp INT NOT NULL,
  ResponseTime REAL NOT NULL,
  IpAddress INT NOT NULL,
  ErrorId INT NOT NULL,
  Flags TINYINT NOT NULL,
  INDEX IX_InLog_UrlId NONCLUSTERED (UrlId)
)

CREATE TABLE OutLog (
  Id BIGINT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  UrlId BIGINT NOT NULL,
  ApiId SMALLINT NOT NULL,
  Timestamp INT NOT NULL,
  ResponseTime REAL NOT NULL,
  HttpStatus TINYINT NOT NULL,
  ErrorId INT NOT NULL,
  INDEX IX_OutLog_UrlId NONCLUSTERED (UrlId)
)
```

Inserts occur through the following procedure. Each application instance flushes buffered records every minute. Each minute there are 800-1200 new rows sent to this insert procedure, and they are submitted in batches - currently 400 rows at a time are sent through the table-valued parameter to the stored procedure. Most rows sent to this procedure are new and result in a table insert.

Primary key ID's are generated in the application, not with auto-increment in the DB. ID's are returned to the application so it can cache these log values and associate future duplicates without querying the DB again. Each minute about half of the UrlLog rows are new and about half are already in application memory. We also assume the Hash is collision-free. In the exceedingly rare case of a collision it is acceptable to have an incorrect Url association.

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[UrlInsertTableType] AS TABLE (
    Id BIGINT NOT NULL,
    Hash UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL,
    Protocol TINYINT NOT NULL,
    DomainId SMALLINT NOT NULL,
    Path NVARCHAR(4000) NOT NULL,
    Query NVARCHAR(4000) NOT NULL)

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[LogUrls]
    @Urls [dbo].[UrlInsertTableType] READONLY
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON
    DECLARE @FINAL_ID BIGINT
    DECLARE @ID BIGINT
    DECLARE @HASH UNIQUEIDENTIFIER
    DECLARE @PROTOCOL TINYINT
    DECLARE @DOMAINID SMALLINT
    DECLARE @PATH NVARCHAR(4000)
    DECLARE @QUERY NVARCHAR(4000)

    CREATE TABLE #UrlInsertTemp (
        Id BIGINT NOT NULL,
        Hash UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL
    )

    BEGIN TRAN
    DECLARE CUR CURSOR LOCAL FAST_FORWARD FOR
        SELECT Id, Hash, Protocol, DomainId, Path, Query FROM @Urls
    OPEN CUR
    WHILE 1=1
    BEGIN
        FETCH NEXT FROM CUR INTO @ID, @HASH, @PROTOCOL, @DOMAINID, @PATH, @QUERY
        IF @@FETCH_STATUS = -1 BREAK
        SET @FINAL_ID = NULL
        SELECT @FINAL_ID = Id FROM Url WHERE Hash=@HASH
        IF @FINAL_ID IS NULL BEGIN
          INSERT INTO Url (Id, Hash, Protocol, DomainId, Path, Query)
          VALUES (@ID, @HASH, @PROTOCOL, @DOMAINID, @PATH, @QUERY)
          SELECT @FINAL_ID = @ID
        END
        INSERT INTO #UrlInsertTemp (Id, Hash) VALUES (@FINAL_ID, @HASH)
    END
    CLOSE CUR
    DEALLOCATE CUR
    COMMIT
    SELECT Id, Hash AS [Key] FROM #UrlInsertTemp
```

Deletes occur through the following procedure. Application code calls the procedure in a loop until it has reached the largest Url.Id.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[DeleteUrls]
    @LastId BIGINT
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON
    DECLARE @ID BIGINT
    DECLARE @FOUND BIGINT
    BEGIN TRAN
    DECLARE CUR CURSOR LOCAL FAST_FORWARD FOR
        SELECT TOP 200 Id FROM UrlLog WHERE Id > @LastId ORDER BY Id
    OPEN CUR
    WHILE 1=1
    BEGIN
        FETCH NEXT FROM CUR INTO @ID
        IF @@FETCH_STATUS = -1 BREAK
        SELECT @FOUND = Id FROM InLog WHERE UrlId=@ID
        IF @FOUND IS NULL BEGIN
            SELECT @FOUND = Id FROM OutLog WHERE UrlId=@ID
            IF @FOUND IS NULL BEGIN
                DELETE FROM UrlLog WHERE Id=@ID
            END
        END
    END
    CLOSE CUR
    DEALLOCATE CUR
    COMMIT
    SELECT @ID
```

App's calling pseudo-code:

```
topId = GetLargestUrlLogId()
lastId = 0
while (lastId < topId)
  lastId = executeDeleteUrlProcedure(lastId)
```

Any suggestions for how one might change the way rows are deleted or inserted to help them play nicer together?

Comment: what is your transaction isolation level?...and do you really need cursors?

Comment: @terrybozzio Read committed. I was thinking I could probably use read uncommitted. I probably don't need the cursor either, but my tsql sproc skills are a bit weak and this is just a first thing I threw together for the delete.

Answer (score 1):

I have a couple of ideas for you that have worked for me in the past.  I find when dealing with such highly transactional there is a lot of 'art' in the 'science' and what works for somebody, doesn't for somebody else.  Hopefully one of these ideas will get your problem solved.

- Try making a queue table of what needs to be deleted.  Using SELECT and WITH(NOLOCK) populate a table that is only 1 column which is the primekey of the table you want to clean.  Then try joining 'chunks' to delete (I've had some success).  Also try simply deleting TOP 1 and joining the tables and looping (for some reason, much better success here.)  My findings have shown that it's not so much the delete that is causing contention, it's the lookup of *what* to delete causing the bigger problem.  These approaches are strange as it's a lot of small transactions which is what we've always been taught is wrong!
- Before your cleaning starts, alter where the logs while cleaning go to a 'hold' table.  Once the cleaning is done, redirect the logging back and import the 'held' data.
- Completely pause the logging.  Do 1 huge delete, resume cleaning.  This is probably not going to be an option.
- Rotate your logging.  Each day have it go to a new table.  Use a view to combine the tables for reading.  To remove data simply drop the oldest table.
- Consider are there other factors to simply improve your overall performance?  Perhaps change the database transaction model to simple or alter the isolation level?

Comment: Your first point is the direction I was thinking, too. I cannot set recovery model to simple - this is an Azure Sql DB, and I was hoping to avoid the complication of redirecting inserts or rotating tables but those strategies would avoid contention. Thanks!